# Why Asp.net MVC3 Chart is not showing the image?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, charts

I have got the following code that produce an image. But I'm getting the an error message.

My code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        eCommerceEntities db = new eCommerceEntities();

        var orders = (from c in db.Orders
                      group c by c.PaymentTypeID into g
                      select new { PaymentTypeID = g.Key, Number = g.Count() });


        var bytes = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
           .AddTitle("Orders")
           .DataBindTable(dataSource: orders, xField: "PaymentTypeID") 
           .GetBytes("png");

        return File(bytes, "image/png");
    }
```

Error Message:

```
Specified method is not supported.
```

Stack Trace:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the _text_ of the stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the chart is trying to enumerate the LINQ query multiple times on one enumerator.

Call `ToList()` before passing the data to the chart.